Multiple instances of an object that is provided through dependency injection
Let's say I have a service that sends emails. This class also needs DI to get settings and add a logger. Here's a trivial implementation:
public interface IEmailService
{
     public string From { get; set; }
     public string To { get; set; }
     public string Cc { get; set; }
     public string Subject { get; set; }
     public string Body { get; set; }
     
     public bool Send();
}

public class EmailService: IEmailService
{
     private readonly IOptions<EMailSettings> _settings;
     private readonly IEmailLogService _logService;

     public string From { get; set; }
     public string To { get; set; }
     public string Cc { get; set; }
     public string Subject { get; set; }
     public string Body { get; set; }
     
     public EmailService(IOptions<EMailSettings> settings, IEmailLogService logService)
     {
          _settings = settings;
          _logService = logService;
     }

     public bool Send()
     {
          SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(_settings.SmtpHost);
          MailMessage message= new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(new MailAddress(From), new MailAddress(To));
          message.Subject = Subject;
          message.Body = Body;
          if (Cc != null)
               message.CC.Add(Cc);

          smtpClient.Send(message);

          logService.log();

          return true;
     }
}

Now I have another service that needs to send emails
public interface ISomeService
{
     public void SendEmails();
}

public class SomeService: ISomeService
{
     private readonly IEmailService _emailService;

     public SomeService(IEmailService emailService)
     {
          _emailService = emailService;
     }

     public void SendEmails()
     {
          // Send first email
          _emailService.From = "sender@example.com";
          _emailService.To = "recipient@example.com";
          _emailService.Cc= "recipient_cc@example.com";
          _emailService.Subject = "My Subject";
          _emailService.Body= "My Message";
          _emailService.Send();

          // Send 2nd email
          _emailService.From = "sender@example.com";
          _emailService.To = "recipient2@example.com";
          _emailService.Subject = "My Subject 2";
          _emailService.Body= "My Message 2";
          _emailService.Send();
     }
}

You can see that _emailService is a shared member and my 2nd email inadvertently has a Cc set from the previous message. Other than having to blank out fields how can I create multiple EmailService objects that don't share data?

How is EmailService registered in the container?

Instead of setting the properties every time you need to use the service, how about you pass them as parameters to the Send method that way you can leave out fields you don't want to send. The other approach might be to have different email services with varying properties.

You should extract all those runtime data properties From, To, Cc, Subject, and Body out of the IEmailService and into a Parameter Object that should be passed into the Send() method. For details on what the underlying problem is and how to mitigate this, see this.

Just replace the example's MoveCustomerCommand with your EmailService, the CustomerId and DestinationAddress properties with your Subject and Body, and the Execute method with Send, and you'll see that the example comes very close to your use case.

EmailService is registered with:
services.AddTransient<IEmailService , EmailService >();

@Steven Thanks. That article is pretty close to what I'm doing. My example was simplified. What could I do if my service needed to retrieve oauth tokens in order to send email? That data doesn't really belong in the 'MoveCustomer' class but it's all that's available that isn't persistent to the handler.

@user1630508: I think the oauth tokens are an example of what is explained with the CustomerRepository example. The Oauth tokens are an implementation detail, and you should find a way to provide the tokens to the EmailService through constructor injection, e.g. by allowing them to be retrieved via some sort of ITokenProvider abstraction. How this token provider gets its tokens depends on how your system is set up, but this discussion warrants a question of its own here at StackOverflow I think.

Right again @Steven. I guess I focused too much on only the top half of your blog.

You should favor keeping application components stateless, or at least let them appear stateless from perspective of the caller. The IEmailService interface is clearly statefull, as it allow you to set the runtime-data values (i.e. From, To, Cc, etc) through its interface.
Your example also exhibits Temporal Coupling, which means that there is an implicit order in which operations need to be called in order for the system to work. This is clearly visible in your question as you say "my 2nd email inadvertently has a Cc set from the previous message." Temporal Coupling is a code smell.
Because you exposed those data properties from IEmailService you are forcing the consuming code to initialize the EmailService component. This leads to complications as described in Injecting runtime data into components.
The solution is to instead pass on those runtime data properties via the Send method:
public interface IEmailService
{
     public bool Send(
         string from, string to, string cc, string subject, string body);
}

To take it one step further, I'd suggest wrapping these values in a Parameter Object:
public record EmailMessage(
    string From, string To, string Cc, string Subject, string Body);

public interface IEmailService
{
     public bool Send(EmailMessage message);
}

You might even choose to use .NET's MailMessage class, as it contains all the desired information already.

Well your second email is still using the same instance of EmailService hence all the properties set previously will still be available to next call to Send()
You should move out all the properties out of email service to another class that acts as a request body, which then also becomes the parameter to Send(),then for every new email you could create a new instance of request class and that should solve the problem
